# Adding a legend to a matplotlib plot of a numpy array with binary data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am writing a program to simulate radioactive decay. I am using a class with a `decay_sim` method which generates a 2D `numpy` array with ones (not decayed) and zeros (decayed) called `self.nuclei`. It is a pseudo-random process, so the array is different each time. I then use a `visual` method to plot this array as a colour grid using `matplotlib`.

This is an example of the `self.nuclei` array:

```
[[1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1]]
```

This is the `visual` method:

```
def visual(self):                                                     
    """Creates a colour map of the nuclei, showing which have decayed.
                                                                      
    """                                                               
    plt.style.use('classic')                                             
                                                                      
    plt.title('Radioactive Nuclei')                                   
                                                                      
    plt.pcolormesh(self.nuclei, edgecolors='w', linewidth=1)          
    ax = plt.gca()                                                    
    ax.set_aspect('equal')                                            
    plt.colorbar()                                                    
                                                                      
    plt.show()
```

And this is its output:
[image]

I am looking for a way to add a legend to this plot that can label the decayed and not decayed colours. I am currently using `plt.colorbar()`, but this only gives me values - not a label. Ideally, it should look something like: "red = not decayed" and "blue = decayed" (although I would like the option to change the colour scheme later). I would also like to include the number of decayed/undecayed cells in the legend. I think I could get the number using:

```
import numpy as np

undecayed_no = np.count_nonzero(self.nuclei)
decayed_no = self.nuclei.size - undecayed_no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [custom legend](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) from rectangular patches. The colors for the mesh can be set via [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import numpy as np

nuclei = np.array([[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]])

plt.style.use('classic')

colors = ['dodgerblue', 'crimson']
ax = plt.gca()
ax.pcolormesh(nuclei, edgecolors='w', linewidth=1, cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=color, edgecolor='w') for color in colors]
undecayed_no = np.count_nonzero(nuclei)
decayed_no = nuclei.size - undecayed_no
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements,
          labels=[f"decayed ({decayed_no})", f"non-decayed ({undecayed_no})"],
          loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[1.02, 1])
ax.set_title('Radioactive Nuclei')
plt.tight_layout(pad=4)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: This work perfectly, thanks. I just wanted to ask about the loc option in ax.legend. It says "upper left" but the legend appears to be in the upper right. When I change to upper right, the legend is placed inside the grid. I'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: `loc` goes together with `bbox_to_anchor(x, y)` where `x` is measured from 0 at the left of the axes area to 1 at the right. So 1.02 is just outside.  Similarly, y goes from 0 at the bottom to 1 at the top. The box is a bit lower than the top because of some padding. "upper left" means the upper left point of the legend is at the anchor point.   If you don't provide an anchor, the legend is put inside the axes (overlapping with the squares in this case).